# Lagrangian density of second order hyperbolic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

It's been some hours now that I am trying to find the Lagrangian density of the following hyperbolic PDE with variable coefficients and $c_{ij}=c_{ji}(x)$
$$
\partial^2_t u - c_{ij}\partial_i\partial_ju = 0 \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty) \tag{$*$} \label{hypeq}
$$
So, if we define, for example, the Lagrangian density to be
$$
L(\nabla_{t,x}u,u,x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\big( u_t^2 - c_{ij}\partial_iu\partial_ju\big)
$$
taking the first variation of the functional
$$
I[u] = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\int_\Omega L(\nabla_{t,x}u,u,x,t)\ \mathrm{d}^nx \mathrm{d} t
$$
we see that the associated Euler-Lagrange equation is (assuming I am correct)
$$
\partial^2_tu - c_{ij}\partial_j\partial_iu - \color{red}{\partial_ic_{ij}\partial_ju} = 0
$$
Any ideas/hints on how to drop the second term, i.e. find the $L(\cdot)$ associated with \eqref{hypeq}?

Also, is there any possibility that a Lagrangian density does not exist at all for the above equation?

Comment: FWIW, the red term [together with a multiplicative factor $\sqrt{|\det(c_{k\ell})|}$ in the Lagrangian] are quite natural in order to maintain covariance if $c^{ij}$ are components of an inverse metric tensor.

Comment: I am not so familiar with the tensor calculus terminology so I didn't understand the point. Does it have to do with Lorentz invariance?